# Jetpack compoes lazycolumn skipping frames (lagging)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Hi i'm trying to implement a `lazycolumn` of a list of posts, I tested it on the emulator api 21 and 29 and it looks kinda smooth on the api 29 it's a little bit laggy, when I tested it on a physical device it was lagging, It looks like it's skipping frames or something..

I tried to remove some views that uses `imageVector` to see if that was the problem and still the same problem.

This is my composable view:

```
@Composable
fun HomePostView(
    category: String,
    imagesUrl: List<String> = listOf(imageHolder),
    doctorProfileImage: String = imageUrl,
    title: String,
    subTitle: String
) {


    Card(
        shape = PostCardShape.large, modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 3.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {

        Column {

            PostTopView(
                category = category,
                onOptionsClicked = { /*TODO option click*/ },
                onBookmarkClicked = {/*TODO bookmark click*/ })

            CoilImage(
                data = imagesUrl[0],
                fadeIn = true,
                contentDescription = "post_image",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .requiredHeight(190.dp)
                    .padding(horizontal = contentPadding),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

            PostDoctorContent(
                doctorProfileImage = doctorProfileImage,
                title = title,
                subTitle = subTitle
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(contentPadding))

            PostBottomView(likesCount = 293, commentsCount = 22)

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(contentPadding))

        }


    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))


}


@Composable
private fun PostDoctorContent(doctorProfileImage: String, title: String, subTitle: String) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = contentPadding)
    ) {

        CoilImage(data = doctorProfileImage,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            contentDescription = null,
            fadeIn = true,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(30.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .clickable {
                    /*Todo on doctor profile clicked*/
                })


        Column {
            Text(
                text = title, fontSize = 14.sp, maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = contentPadding)
            )

            Text(
                text = subTitle,
                fontSize = 11.sp,
                color = LightTextColor,
                maxLines = 2,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = contentPadding)
            )
        }
    }


}

@Composable
private fun PostBottomView(likesCount: Long, commentsCount: Long) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = contentPadding),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        Row(
            Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50))
                .clickable { /*Todo on like clicked*/ }
                .padding(5.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_heart),
                contentDescription = "Like"
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Text(text = likesCount.toString(), fontSize = 9.sp)
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.width(20.dp))

        Row(
            Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50))
                .clickable { /*Todo on comment clicked*/ }
                .padding(5.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_comment),
                contentDescription = "Comment"
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Text(text = commentsCount.toString(), fontSize = 9.sp)
        }


    }
}

@Composable
private fun PostTopView(
    category: String,
    onOptionsClicked: () -> Unit,
    onBookmarkClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {

        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            IconButton(onClick = onOptionsClicked) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_threedots),
                    contentDescription = "Options",
                    tint = Color.Unspecified
                )
            }

            Text(text = category, fontSize = 16.sp, color = LightTextColor)

        }

        IconButton(onClick = onBookmarkClicked) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_bookmark),
                contentDescription = "Bookmark"
            )
        }

    }
}
```

and the lazyColumn:

```
LazyColumn(contentPadding = paddingValues , state = state ) {
    item {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

        DoctorsList(
            viewModel.doctorListData.value,
            onCardClicked = {})
    }
    items(30) {  post ->
        HomePostView(
            category = "Public Health ",
            title = "Food Importance",
            subTitle = "you should eat every day it's healthy and important for you, and drink water every 2 hours and what you should do is you should run every day for an hour"
        )

    }
}
```

**Note: I'm still not using a viewmodel i'm just testing the view with fake data**

Comment: try use key on `items(30, keys = { it } )` make more smooth, make but yeah android compose still not good for performance since its beta

Comment: @RofieSagara Same problem :/

Comment: We are making significant changes that will hopefully land shortly which will improve this. First `LazyList` will now precompose rows when time allows between frames. Second, rows will now share layout information between rows similar to `RecyclerView`. This is still under active development so other changes are likely.

Comment: @chuckj Compose is now stable. How come LazyColumn has such poor performance still ? Is it at least somewhere high on list of issues over there at Google ?

Comment: @TheJudge I am suffering from the same issue. I loved Compose but this is the very thing that pissed me off. Maybe in a simple column it's a bit of lag, but if you try to use LazyVerticalGrid (experimental api) or even when I implemented it myself using LazyColumn with Rows that hold items, it's still the same, super laggy behavior that's just not usable at all. I have an older version of my app written in Java and uses RecyclerView, super smooth. I don't want to push an update that makes the user experience worse.

Comment: This is like a very underrated question. How come on earth nobody ask about what's happening here?

Comment: Compose is a external library and during development will JIT until a profile is present on the deployment device. This is normal for any external library. To get a good idea of how it will perform after the profile is generated, run a release build with R8 enabled and ensure you run the AOT manually on the device.

Comment: Are you running a debug build or a release build with R8? They'll be a bit difference.

Comment: Have you tried looking into Android Studio profiler? I think you can find out what exactly is taking time to render and optimize your layouts.

Answer (score 4):

This may not work for anyone else but on an earlier version (`1.0.0-beta01`) I saw a very large improvement in performance when I switched

```
lazy(items) { item ->
    ...
}
```

to

```
items.forEach { item ->
    lazy {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have no idea why and I'm not sure if this is still the case in later versions but its worth checking. So for the example given in the question, that would mean changing

```
items(30) {
    ...
}
```

to

```
repeat(30) {
    item { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: Make sure your new LazyColumn compose element is not within a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.**

After some investigation the solution to this issue for us was the view in which the LazyColumn was constrained.

Our project uses a combination of Jetpack Compose and the older XML layout files. Our new compose elements were embedded within a RelativeLayout of an existing XML file. This was where the problem was. The compose element would be given the entire screen and then the onMeasure function of the compose element was called to re-configure the view and add our bottom nav bar...this onMeasure was called over and over again, which also in the case of a LazyColumn the re-measuring was throwing out the cache as the height had changed.

The solution for us was to change the RelativeLayout that contained both the new compose element and the bottom nav bar and replace it with a ConstraintLayout. This prevented the onMeasure from being called more than twice and gave a massive performance increase.

Comment: A LinearLayout was much more performant than a RelativeLayout for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build release build with turn off debug logs. should be works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So far I know that there is an issue with the API when it comes to performance ...But what I found is this

Actually, In my case, I was just loading the image with 2980*3750 pixels image. I just crunched my resources to shorter pixels by some other tools

Now the lag is not present...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after I set the height of `ComposeView` to a specific value, it make `LazyColumn` scroll smooth.
Therefore, I create a `XML` file like

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

`Fragment`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.doOnLayout {
        compose.layoutParams.height = view.height
        compose.requestLayout()
    }
}
```

I know `ComposeView` height already `match_parent` so set the height for it again on `Fragment` seem useless. However, without setting the height, `LazyColumn` will lagging when scroll.
I am not sure if it will work in all device but work well on my `Pixel` and `Xiomi`.

Comment: Sadly didn't make any difference for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPGs or PNGs in your project then check for their size, images having larger size causes a lots of lagging issues on low end devices.
I was having the same issue with my simple LazyColumn list and turned out I was using a JPG having size larger than 2MBs.